# Is that suggested to delete .map files from the build generated by ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, production-environment

I am developing large scale application in ReactJS and having a concern with huge **build size issue**.

After generation of build (Production Mode) in ReactJS, I found that build size was too much heavy and after research, I got that you can **delete source map** files (.map) by having below configuration in **package.json** file.

```
 "postbuild": "rimraf build/**/*.map",
```

Consequently, my build size got reduced by 80% which makes me more than happy.

However, I am still having a doubt that, aforesaid is the best solution or not?

Comment: source map is better used for the dev env alone. Having it off on prod is a good move.

Comment: @ValerianPereira why? I challenge you to give an exceptionally compelling reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What are source maps?

Source maps help debugging your bundle file in the browser by reconstructing the original source from the bundled code.

### Should I use source maps in production?

Source maps don't slow down your page load so it's not a problem to include them in your production environments. They will only be downloaded when you open devtools in the browser. However, since source maps enable the browser to reconstruct the original source from the bundled code, anyone with devtools can peak at your source easily (it's not impossible without source maps, just not easy). That's why the common practice is to only include source maps in development environments.

### How do I disable source maps?

You can disable source map generation during the build.

If you are using the latest `create-react-app`, in your `webppack.config.prod` change this line

```
const shouldUseSourceMap = process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP !== 'false';
```

to

```
const shouldUseSourceMap = false
```

and your prod build files won't include source maps.

*Note: You should have ejected your create-react-app to access your webpack config files*

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion.

Is that good idea to run via postbuild script as an alternative solution?

Comment: What if I am not using webpack?

Comment: Even if you are not using `webpack`, source maps are generated by whatever build tool you are using. There's nothing wrong in removing the source maps via a post build script. But if you can prevent generating the source maps in the first place, then it will save you a few seconds of build time.

Comment: @KrupalPatel If this answer helped with solving your question, pl mark it as accepted. It will help others stumbling across a similar problem.

Comment: @DineshPandiyan you have'nt really explained why. The question really asks why, not how.

Comment: @DineshPandiyan 'but it's generally a good idea to not include them in the production env if they are too heavy." Why? This answer is still too vague and smells of the screaming monkies with the garden hose story.

Comment: Updated the answer for brevity

Answer (score 0):

I have found that in commercial reality, having source maps in **any environment** saves more time than people "fear it costs".

And this is what it comes down to. People fear it.

What is it you're obfuscating anyway? bad practices? insecure code? Not providing sourcemaps won't save you there.

If you're trying to save on peformance? They're only loaded when devtools are opened, at which point... oh look you don't have sourcemaps what a shame, debugging is now magnitudes more difficult.

Answer (score -2):

If you come here and are using webpack, simply set `devtool` to false in your config to disable webpack (currently @5) from generating .map files.

```js
module.exports = {
    devtool: false
}
```

Nothing else worked for me besides that, even setting `mode: "production"` did not work.

Comment: @airtonix Setting the `devtool` option generates .map files so that you can step through and view line numbers/code if you are using webpack. By setting `devtool` to false, these .map files are not generated which reduces the build size.

Comment: Downvoted because you didn't answer the question: `Is that suggested to delete .map files from the build generated by ReactJS?`... the answer is always no.